# Android 10 manage pdf file from scoped/external storage

Tags: android, file, android-jetpack-compose, file-management, file-manager

I have problem with file management in external/scoped storage in Android 10.

Long story short, I'm downloading pdf from Internet, saving in Documents/Subfolder, and delete if i need.
I'm using these functions:

**Downloading file**
I'm just using Retrofit

```
@Streaming
  @GET
  suspend fun downloadFile(@Url url: String): ResponseBody
```

**Saving file**

```
fun saveFile(
  inputStream: InputStream,
  context: Context,
  fileNameWithType: FileNameWithType,
  contentLength: Long,
  outputStream: FileOutputStream,
  onProgress: (IntPercent) -> Unit
) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    saveFileSdk29AndAbove(
      inputStream = inputStream,
      context = context,
      fileNameWithType = fileNameWithType,
      contentLength = contentLength,
      onProgress = onProgress
    )
  } else {
    saveFileSdk28AndBelow(
      inputStream = inputStream,
      outputStream = outputStream,
      contentLength = contentLength,
      onProgress = onProgress
    )
  }
}
```

FileNameWithType -> Its just a regular String for example "File.pdf"

**Constants for both functions below**

```
const val BYTE_ARRAY_SIZE = 8192
const val MAX_PROGRESS = 100
const val START_OFFSET = 0
const val MIN_BYTES = -1
const val START_PROGRESS_BYTES = 0L
```

**Sdk 29 and above**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun saveFileSdk29AndAbove(
  inputStream: InputStream,
  context: Context,
  fileNameWithType: FileNameWithType,
  contentLength: Long,
  onProgress: (IntPercent) -> Unit
) {

  inputStream.use { stream ->
    val relativeLocation =
      Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + File.separator.toString() + SUB_FOLDER_NAME

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
      put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileNameWithType)
      put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation)
    }

    val contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    val resolver = context.contentResolver

    val uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues)
      ?: throw BytesException("Uri should not be null.")

    context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w").use { parcelFileDescriptor ->
      parcelFileDescriptor?.let {
        FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor).use { fileOutputStream ->

          val data = ByteArray(size = BYTE_ARRAY_SIZE)
          var progressBytes = START_PROGRESS_BYTES

          while (true) {
            val bytes = stream.read(data)

            if (bytes == MIN_BYTES) {
              break
            }

            fileOutputStream.write(data, START_OFFSET, bytes)
            progressBytes += bytes

            onProgress(((progressBytes * MAX_PROGRESS) / contentLength).toInt())

          }

          //region Check bytes
          
          if (progressBytes < contentLength) {
            throw BytesException("Missing bytes. Should be $contentLength but was $progressBytes")
          }

          if (progressBytes > contentLength) {
            throw BytesException("Too many bytes. Should be $contentLength but was $progressBytes")
          }
          
          //endregion

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sdk 28 and below**

```
fun saveFileSdk28AndBelow(
  inputStream: InputStream,
  onProgress: (IntPercent) -> Unit,
  outputStream: FileOutputStream,
  contentLength: Long,
) {

  inputStream.use { stream ->

    val data = ByteArray(size = BYTE_ARRAY_SIZE)
    var progressBytes = START_PROGRESS_BYTES

    //region Read bytes from response and save bytes to file

    while (true) {
      val bytes = stream.read(data)

      if (bytes == MIN_BYTES) {
        break
      }

      outputStream.write(data, START_OFFSET, bytes)
      progressBytes += bytes

      onProgress(((progressBytes * MAX_PROGRESS) / contentLength).toInt())
    }

    //endregion

    //region Check bytes

    if (progressBytes < contentLength)
      throw BytesException("Missing bytes. Should be $contentLength but was $progressBytes")

    if (progressBytes > contentLength)
      throw BytesException("Too many bytes. Should be $contentLength but was $progressBytes")

    //endregion
  }
}
```

**Deleting file**

```
fun deleteFile(
  context: Context,
  filePath: FilePath,
  fileNameWithType: FileNameWithType
) =
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    deleteFileSdk29AndAbove(
      context = context,
      fileNameWithType = fileNameWithType
    )
  } else {
    deleteFileSdk28AndBelow(
      filePath = filePath,
      fileNameWithType = fileNameWithType
    )
  }
```

**Sdk 29 and above**

```
@RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun deleteFileSdk29AndAbove(context: Context, fileNameWithType: FileNameWithType): Boolean {
  val resolver = context.contentResolver
  val contentUri = getUriByFileName(fileNameWithType, contentResolver = resolver)
  return contentUri?.let {
    val rowsDeleted = resolver.delete(
      it, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", arrayOf(fileNameWithType)
    )
    rowsDeleted > 0
  } ?: false
}
```

**Implementation of getUriByFileName**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun getUriByFileName(fileName: FileName, contentResolver: ContentResolver): Uri? {
  val fileId: Long
  val fileUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
  val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID)
  val cursor = contentResolver.query(
    fileUri,
    projection,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
    arrayOf(fileName),
    null
  )!!
  cursor.moveToFirst()
  val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0])
  fileId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex)
  cursor.close()
  return Uri.parse("$fileUri/$fileId")
}
```

**Sdk 28 and below**

```
private fun deleteFileSdk28AndBelow(
  filePath: FilePath,
  fileNameWithType: FileNameWithType
): Boolean {
  val file = File(filePath, fileNameWithType)
  return file.delete()
}
```

**More details**

I'm creating file in extrenal storage like:

```
  val downloadFile = File(filePath, fileNameWithType)
  if (!downloadFile.exists()) {
    downloadFile.createNewFile()
  }
```

filePath -> Similar as above is just a String

External storage path looks like:

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)!!.absolutePath +
      File.separator.toString() + SUB_FOLDER_NAME
```

I have permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Before, doing anything with file I'm checking permissions, if permissions are granted, navigate to screen with file, else show dialog with short information why i need this permissions.

**Conclusions**
I was checking this code in Android: 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12. Code work perfectly fine in all OS version except 10.

In Android 10 I cannot delete file.

I get information about that amount of removed row number is 1, but file is still in file system.

I was combining method for sdk 28 and 29, without any success.

**Summary**
I decided to using MediaStore for sdk 29 and above and simple File for sdk 28 and below. If you have any tips or suggestions for what to improve or what I am doing wrong, please comment. Thank you for your time.

**Stack**
Retrofit, Compose